# Outer Glow Effect on UILabels

Tags: swift, uilabel, photoshop

I'm trying to match a Photoshop effect to a swift UILabel
and failing.

Photoshop has

```
BlendMode: Multiply
Opacity:   68%
Noise:     0%
Technique: Softer
Spread:    14%
Size:      16px
Range:     50%
```

How does this translate to swift's

```
layer.shadowOffset
layer.shadowRadius
layer.shadowOpcacity
```

thanks in advance

Comment: A glow is not a simple shadow if I remember correctly, because it's all around (a sahdow is in one direction) It's more like a stroke with a "gradient" (it goes less intense the more it leaves the shape). Also, I don't think that we can easily replicate all the params you have. And lastly, please show a sample of what it looks like in Photoshop, how it's rendered and we might help you with a workaround.

Comment: @Larme Although I also have the feeling that glow might be more than a shadow, technically the shadow _doesn't_ have to be constrained to one direction (if you pass `.zero` to the offset, the shadow is spreading like lighting the object from directly above) and also 'feels' like a gradient where fades from full intensity to transparency. Having said that, I would also love to know more about this from someone with a stronger background in the subject :)

Comment: And here is an image of a quick playground 'experiment' demonstrating the effect: https://imgur.com/a/gEoYcXg

Answer (score 0):

```
Opacity -> layer.shadowOpcacity
Size -> layer.shadowRadius
Angle + Distance -> layer.shadowOffset
```

The rest of the properties don't have a matching option on a CALayer. To reproduce them you'd have to do some custom drawing using [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics)